# Weird Bootstrap button Behavior

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

```
  <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#" role="button">Apple Music</a>
```

On full resolution works fine

[full resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiBTP.png)

On a certain resolution bootstrap behaves like this

[weird in small resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj0qA.png)

In smartphone resolution works again`

[Smartphone resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRHVl.png)

Comment: Please add some code to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is normally related to a combination of `white-space: normal` and `word-break: break-all`. I am pretty certain that your button has the `word-break` definition. You could check that in your code.

The easiest way to override this would be to change the `white-space` definition to `white-space: nowrap` but that also depends on what you want to achieve with the button text. If you want it to keep breaking, but only complete words you could eliminate the `word-break` definition or override it to `word-break: inherit`.